# Installation issues in react-native for windows

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have some problems in installing react-native for windows

Check my screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whooo this is an old post but I just went through this process and think I have the solution. You need to add react-native to your Path system variable under Environment Variables. Check out [step 4 in this guide that I wrote](http://bitvbit.blogspot.com/2016/07/react-native-android-apps-on-windows.html) and it should make it possible to run the react-native command.

The path you need to add to your path variable will be: `C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm`